# Non-commutative class of linear time-varying systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this kind of problem?

$\frac{d}{d t} 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\Omega_1(t)\\\Omega_2(t)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\alpha*(\cos(2kt)-1)&\alpha \sin(2kt)\\\alpha \sin(2kt)&\beta-\alpha*(\cos(2kt)+1)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}\Omega_1(t)\\\Omega_2(t)\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]$

with the form of $x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$.

I've solved the case of $\beta=0$.

Here, I want to get the form of the general solution with $\beta\neq 0$.
Is it possible to find the general solutions?

$\textbf{Edit}$: When $\beta=0$,

I follow the method [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207178008961024?needAccess=true&journalCode=tcon20):

(1) Find $A_1=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}0&-k\\k&0\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]$, which satisfies the relation: $A_1$$A(t)$-$A(t)$$A_1$=$A'(t)$

(2) Then get $A_2=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{matrix}0&k\\-k&-\alpha\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]$ by: $A_2$=$A(0)$-$A_1$

(3) The state transition matrix ($\phi$) is then given by:

$\phi(t,0)=\text{Exp}[A_1 t].\text{Exp}[A_2 t]$ (matrix exponetial)

(4) solution is given by: $x(t)=\phi(t,0)x(0)$.

Comment: What is your solution to the case $\beta = 0$?

Comment: @RobertLewis I've edited my post for your question :)

Comment: OK, thanks for the update!

Comment: @RobertLewis Do you have any idea? Thans!

Comment: Maybe.  Thinking on it . . . 